# && and || operators not working as expected

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char c1;
    char c2 = 'B';

    while(c1 != 'B' && c2 == 'B'){

        cout << "Ok!" << endl;

        c1 = 'B';
        //c2 = 'A';

        cout << "c1 = " << c1 << endl << "c2 = " << c2 << endl;
    }
}

/*
    >>OUTPUT<<

    Ok!
    c1 = B
    c2 = B
*/
```

Looking at the simple program above you would think it would be an infinite loop but for some reason it runs thru once and ends. Changing the operator from && to || goes into an infinite loop.

It's as if the && and || operators are swapped. Am I just not seeing it?

Comment: As soon as `c1` is `'B`' the condition is false. Why would you expect this to loop forever?

Comment: You should initialize c1, you're using it before assignment of a value.

Comment: You probably should initialize 'c1' with some value

Comment: `C1 !='B'` becomes false after loop 1

Comment: You seem to be mis-understanding the and operator, when you assign c1 = 'B', the left condition c1 != 'B' is false therefore the && operator is evaluated to false; Both conditons of the and operator have to be true for the expression to be true

Comment: You're just not seeing it.

Comment: You're not seeing two things.   Firstly, `c1` is uniitialised before the loop, so the first test in the loop has undefined behaviour.   If the loop condition happens to be `true` the first time, then the thing you're not seeing is that the loop running once means `&&` is behaving as it required to.   If you don't grasp that, your understanding of what `&&` does is flawed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&&` is AND, `||` is OR

A list of operators can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) and a more detailed explaination, including the order of precedence, of each one can be found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/).

The first time your program arrives at the loop c1 is a uninitialized and reading its value is [undefined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), and probably not 'B', but it could be anything. Therefore `c1 != 'B'` evaluates as true most of the time.
The whole statement of `c1 != 'B' && c2 == 'B'` is therefore `true && true` and the loop runs once.

> Note: Reading an uninitialized value is "Undefined Behavior". This technically makes your whole application undefined and thus invalid. But "Undefined Behavior" can do anything, in this case return a value of not 'B' or potentially in the future a value of 'B' or simply crash.

In the loop you set `c1 = 'B'`, therefore the first condition in the while loop `c1 != 'B'` becomes false, the whole condition then being `false && true`.
since false AND true = false, the loop aborts.

If you swap out the and with an or (`||`), the loop will always run since `c2 == 'B'` will always be true because you don't change it in the loop.

You should [learn how to use a debugger](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and step through your code and examine variables after each step. For very simple problems like this "printf-debugging" works, too. Just dump the contents of your variables and expressions you are interested in to stdout. But you should learn how to use a debugger regardless.

Comment: -  ack.   Since they're no longer needed, I've removed my preceding comments.

Answer (score 3):

`c1` is not initialised, so it's *probably* not `'B'`, i.e. `c1 != 'B'` probably evaluates to true.

Hence the loop is statistically likely to run exactly once and certainly no more than that since you explicitly set `c1` to `'B'` in the loop body.

(Note that in general the behaviour on reading an uninitialised variable is *undefined*, but a `char` type is a notable exception.)

Comment: I think the last sentence is true for `unsigned char` only.

Comment: @P.W Not from C++14.

Comment: Okay. Just want to know if I am misreading what C++17 states on this: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#12

Comment: @P.W Nice link. The way I read that is that everything is fine until you assign to the `int`, formally due to the fact that an `int` can contain a trap representation.

Comment: Learned something new +1.